# Javascript to sort elements

Tags: sorting, javascript

I've need to sort some items on the page where the CMS I use doesn't provide for this. I can add some tags dynamically, but I need help here with some Javascript that would put the items in the correct order.

Further at the top of the HTML page I've got an 'event selector', e.g.:

```
<div class="w-embed">
    <div event-selector="weddings"></div>
</div>
```

This would determine which set of the sorting numbers to use. Each item includes some code with a sort number from each set. **w-dyn-item** are the elements that need sorting.

```
<div class="w-dyn-list">
  <div class="w-dyn-items">

    <div class="w-dyn-item">
      <div class="w-embed">
        <div sort-event="conference" sort="09"></div>
        <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="110"></div>
        <div sort-event="wedding" sort="2"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        Content A
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-dyn-item">
      <div class="w-embed">
        <div sort-event="conference" sort="06"></div>
        <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="60"></div>
        <div sort-event="wedding" sort="1"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        Content B
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="w-dyn-item">
      <div class="w-embed">
        <div sort-event="conference" sort="01"></div>
        <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="54"></div>
        <div sort-event="wedding" sort="3"></div>
      </div>
      <div>
        Content C
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

The logic would be: Sort **w-dyn-item** elements by using the 'sort-event' numbers that correspond to the 'event-selector' (from smallest to largest number).

The site's using jQuery if that's any help.

I've put it into a Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/j2rqze8p

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you can actually sort the elements with jQuery.

```js
var sortPropertyName = $('.w-embed [event-selector]').attr('event-selector');
var sortAttrValues = {
 'weddings': 'wedding',
 'exhibitions': 'exhibition',
 'conferences': 'conference'
};
var sortAttributeValue = sortAttrValues[sortPropertyName];

if(!sortAttributeValue) {
 throw new Error('Unable to sort. Sort attribute value not found.')
}

var attrSelector = '[sort-event="' + sortAttributeValue + '"]';

var $container = $('.w-dyn-items');
var $items = $container.children('.w-dyn-item');

$items.sort(function (item1, item2) {
 var item1Value = $(item1).find(attrSelector).attr('sort');
 var item2Value = $(item2).find(attrSelector).attr('sort');

 return parseInt(item1Value) - parseInt(item2Value);

});

$items.detach().appendTo($container);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="w-dyn-list">
 <div class="w-embed">
  <div event-selector="weddings"></div>
 </div>


 <div class="w-dyn-items">

  <div class="w-dyn-item">
   <div class="w-embed">
    <div sort-event="conference" sort="09"></div>
    <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="110"></div>
    <div sort-event="wedding" sort="2"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Content A
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-dyn-item">
   <div class="w-embed">
    <div sort-event="conference" sort="06"></div>
    <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="60"></div>
    <div sort-event="wedding" sort="1"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Content B
   </div>
  </div>

  <div class="w-dyn-item">
   <div class="w-embed">
    <div sort-event="conference" sort="01"></div>
    <div sort-event="exhibition" sort="54"></div>
    <div sort-event="wedding" sort="3"></div>
   </div>
   <div>
    Content C
   </div>
  </div>

 </div>
</div>
```

There are two moments.
First, as I noticed the value of event-selector is plural whereas sort-event are singular.
I solved this by having a hash to match one to another.

The another thing is that you might need to run this script on 'event-selector' change if you want the sort to by dynamic. But it's basically a matter of a different discussion.